# 3D rotation ratios via mouse placement on screen - Java

Tags: java, 3d, rotation, angle

I am making a 3D game in which the player can rotate their view point via the mouse to look around the environment. I firstly just did x and y rotation via vertical and horizontal movement of the mouse and z via another control. But after playing the game I realised it did not rotate correctly. NOTE: I have a global variable matrix which represents the player's angle (3x1), at 0,0,0 it seems to work correctly as up or down is a direct x axis rotation and right or left is a direct y axis rotation, but if I move my camera diagonally for example then left doesn't directly correlate to a y axis rotation anymore.
Visually on a unit circle the players viewpoint wouldn't travel the full circumference anymore and would travel in a circle that is smaller that the circumference. This is the current code (x and yRateOfRot is the ratio of how far away from the centre the cursor is in each direction between -1 and 1):

```
private static void changeRotation(){
    angle.set(Matrix.add(angle.matrix,new double[][]{
            {ROTATION_SPEED * camera.xRateOfRot()},
            {ROTATION_SPEED * camera.yRateOfRot()},
            {ROTATION_SPEED * camera.zRateOfRot()}}));
}
```

I have looked at this source http://paulbourke.net/geometry/rotate/ and understand how to rotate via an arbitrary axis which I could do but I am not sure how to correlate this into getting a ratio to find out what the x,y and z change would be for looking in a specific direction i.e. at 0,0,0 the ratio of looking up would be x:1, y:0, z:0 but then at another angle the ratios would be different as looking up no longer means only an x rotation. Any information would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Look into *pitch, yaw and roll*. You should keep track of them separately as pitch needs to be clamped. Also, remember that the order of multiplication matters. In pseudocode the final rotation matrix is given by: `Matrix.RotationZ(yaw) * Matrix.RotationY(pitch) * Matrix.RotationX(roll)`, when the starting direction is `(1, 0, 0)`.

Comment: It can be envisioned that angle[0][0] is pitch, angle[1][0] is yaw and angle[2][0] is roll, the player starting direction is 0,0,1. The problem is that when I pitch so I am looking directly upwards then relative to the player yaw is now roll with it not changing the player perspective. I need some sort of way to change yaw, pitch and roll relative to the player's current direction in terms of the original yaw pitch and roll angles so that when the player looks left his viewpoint always moves left rather than just being a static axis rotation.

Comment: That's called gimbal lock, and is an intrinsic property of Euler angles. What do you mean by "viewpoints moves left"? Do you mean strafing, or like how a third person camera orbits the player?

Comment: The player in my game is a single point with the camera being at said point and is rotatable. By "viewpoint moves left" I mean the player looking left from their current direction. In the game the player can rotate roll, so if they're right side up for example, "viewpoint moves left" is the camera rotating anti-clockwise from a top down view of the player but then if they flip upside down them looking to their "left" is a clockwise rotation from a top down view. I wish to be able to calculate what rotating the camera "left" is in terms of x y and z rotation.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. That can be accomplished by putting the yaw rotation matrix first: `Matrix.RotationY(pitch) * Matrix.RotationX(roll) * Matrix.RotationZ(yaw)` (although at this point it would be inaccurate to call them "pitch" and "yaw"). I recommend recomputing the corresponding rotation matrix every time when you change one of the angles, as otherwise we would need to e.g. compute the "up" vector of the camera and a rotation matrix around it (a more costly operation).

Comment: I think that might be what I am doing wrong. I am doing rotations via x y and z rather than yaw, roll and pitch... I have a angle value for x y and z which describes the player direction with my display being said rotation but just the transpose(reverse). But how to I rotate with pitch roll and yaw is the issue then, I don't understand how to display my graphics through a different method as all my stuff is basic maths rather than using any other class to display. Maybe I should look more into that instead.

Comment: If you have a (4x4) camera matrix, then you can set the rotation part (the top-left 3x3 sub-matrix) to the *transpose* (= inverse) of the rotation you want to apply to the camera. Unless you are using the proper convention for a projection setup, we cannot help you much further.